# how to fill (write) datacolumn to list<>?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, n-tier-architecture

I am trying to get a datacolumn with values (already filled in data table) and write it in an auto property present in access layer. Currently, the method i am using is fetching data from sql and passing the values to gird. I am trying to use that method and already filled datatable but the problem is, auto property is only reading column name and as a result i am getting column name in another control (list box). The below is my method in BLL.

```
DAL d = new DAL();

public Object getfeechallan(Bal B) 
{
sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommand("select * from tblfee where fee_challan_No like @abc,d.con");
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@abc","%"+b.fee_challan_No+"%");
datatable dt=d.getdatafilter(cmd);
foreach(datacolumn dd in dt.columns)
{
if(dd.columnname=="ftid")
{
list<DataColumn> dc = new list<DataColumn>();
dc.Add(dd);
b.abc=dc;
}

} return dt;


}
```

My method in DAL is

```
public Datatable getdatafilter(SqlCommand CMD)
{
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(CMD);
Datatable dt = new Datatable ();
da.Fill(dt);
return dt;
}
```

Auto Property is

```
public list<DataColumn> abc {get; set;}
```

Comment: When you say "datacolumn with values" what do you mean exactly please? Are you saying that not all the data columns properties are set when you add it to the list?

Comment: I mean i want to copy the values contained in this specific column named 'ftid' to list..

Comment: Just so we're clear then. You want the actual data column? not the data in the rows of the datatable?  Data columns are exactly that. A collection of columns on a data table. They have properties like name, datatype and length.

Comment: yeah data from just one column

Comment: well looking at your code... aside from continuing to loop through all columns once you've found the column you want... i can't see any problem. Move the "return dt" under the assignment of the list to the "Bal" object to get out as soon as you've found col "ftid" if thats the only col you want. Which value incidentally is it that's missing off the column when you look at it in the list assigned to "Bal".

Comment: Ok i will move it there but then there may be compile error as type method return calls does not works in loop.

Comment: You are returning "object" You need to return a DataTable.

Comment: Secondly, non value is missing. When i look into BAL property after, it has just one value and that is the name of column nothing else. I want to get the data present in that column and fill it in the list

Comment: Ah... that's the point I was making with my 1st comments. Columns are nothing to do with table data... they are just column headers. I'll post you an answer to get all data.

Comment: all done.. i've changed the list to be of string.. and the return type to datatable... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. so the below should do it.

```
public DataTable getfeechallan(Bal b)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sdb = new SqlDataAdapter("Select count(*) From reserve", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<string> dc = new List<string>();

        sdb.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dd in dt.Rows)
        {
           dc.Add(dd["ftid"].ToString());
        }

        Bal.abc = dc;

        return dt;
    }
```

One other observation. Unless you need the datatable returning, change the return type to "void". I presume all the data you need is now in the "Bal" object.

Comment: let me try and i will get back with results. Thanks by the way

Comment: Void wont work as i am providing this method as a datasource to gridview and gridview does not accepts void bcoz void does not return anything actually.

Comment: That's fine... was just thinking out loud :)

Comment: Hi.. did you get this sorted?

Comment: i didnt get a chance yet. i will comment as soon as i have tried it

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get a list contains all values in certain column
you can not just ref the column
you need to loop all rows of that column

```
List<object> values = new List<object>();
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count(); i++)
{
    values.Add(dt[i]["columnName"]);
}
```

Comment: That should work. I was missing this point that i have to loop all rows to gets column contents. thanks Ray H